# Add data to a particular line in a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to build a script that adds comma separated values into a particular line in a file.

Say I have a file with contents:

```
DL1 : abc@kk.com,cde@kk.com,xyz@kk.com
DL2 : hjk@kk.com,nbv@kk.com,tuy@kk.com
```

I need to add `ghj@kk.com` to `DL1 :`

Comment: Please provide a little more information. Where does the data come from? Is this part of a larger script? What does it do? What are the requirements? How is it meant to be used? Is this a school exercise?

Comment: If you find the provided answers to be helpful, you should consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353652) one of them.

Answer (score 5):

To match lines starting with `DL1 :` and add `,ghj@kk.com` to the end (`$`) of them:

```
$ sed '/^DL1 :/ s/$/,ghj@kk.com/' file
DL1 : abc@kk.com,cde@kk.com,xyz@kk.com,ghj@kk.com
DL2 : hjk@kk.com,nbv@kk.com,tuy@kk.com
```

Depending on your requirements and your version of `sed` you can add `-i` to make the transformation in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Simply accomplishing your requirement with `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "DL1" {$0 = $0 ",ghj@kk.com"} 1' file
```

Using GNU awk you can use the `-i` option to make edits inplace otherwise you will need to create a temp file with the output.

---

If you're looking to add this functionality to a shell script you can pass your search and input using awk variables.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

search=$1
addition=$2

awk -v s="$search" -v a="$addition" '$1 == s {$0 = $0 "," a} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple job for the [standard UNIX editor, ed](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html):

```
printf '%s\n' '/^DL1 :/ s/$/,ghj@kk.com/' w q | ed -s input
```

The above prints three newline-separated commands to `ed`:

1. on the line that starts with the text `DL1 :`, search and replace the end-of-line marker (`$`) with `,ghj@kk.com`
2. `w`rite the file to disk
3. `q`uit ed

This has the net effect of adding `,ghj@kk.com` to the end of the `DL1 :` line.