# Remove a string from a particular line

Tags: text-processing, csv

I need to build a script that adds comma separated values into a particular line in a file.

Say I have a file with contents:

```
DL1 : abc@kk.com,cde@kk.com,xyz@kk.com
DL2 : hjk@kk.com,nbv@kk.com,tuy@kk.com
```

now I have to remove `xyz@kk.com` from DL1

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/518006/117549

Answer (score 1):

It's the same pattern like in your related post

```
sed '/^DL1 :/ s/,xyz@kk.com//' file
```

This substitute `,xyz@kk.com` with nothing in lines that start with `DL1 :`.

Comment: ... on the assumption that it's not the first element in the list...

Comment: You're right. Changed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Perl:**

```
perl -lpe 'if (/^DL1 :/) {s/,?xyz\@kk\.com//; s/: \K,//}' file
```

**AWK:**

```
awk '/^DL1 :/ {sub(/,?xyz@kk\.com/,"");sub(": ,",": ")} 1' file
```

**sed:**

```
sed -E '/^DL1 :/ s/,?cde@kk.com//; /^DL1 :/ s/: ,/: /' file
```

**Note:**

These may not be the best tools to manipulate what is essentially a variation of a csv file. I suggest you add more context about where the data comes from and its intended use.